# Codeigniter callback on empty fields?

Tags: forms, codeigniter, callback, validation

I'm having problems with callback on empty fields.

For some reason i need to compare value of field with some other parameters and to make it "required" only if some other conditions are fulfilled buy checking it from callback function.

Unfortunately, if field is empty, callback function is not called.

DO you have any idea how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Where is the code buddy?

Comment: No need for code, it's really described as it is. Plain and simple.

Comment: Code is important. You could have your rules named wrong, your callback function named wrong, etc...

Comment: I believe it is, but definitely that it's not the case here.

Answer (score 2):

This "bug" is actually a "feature" of the Form Validation. If the input is empty and the required rule is not set, then it skips all other rules (even non-callback functions). You can extend (or hack) the validation to continue through all functions even if the input is blank.

In `system/libraries/Form_validation.php` at about line 486, you will see the comment:

```
// If the field is blank, but NOT required, no further tests are necessary
```

You will then see two lines with a `return;` shortly after that comment. The lines for me are at line 498 and line 536 (about 12 and 50 lines after the comment). If you comment out those two lines, then the validation will continue through all function even if the input is blank.

That being said, you can extend the Form Validation by creating a file at `application/libraries/Form_validation.php` and overriding the `_execute` function:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
    protected function _execute($row, $rules, $postdata = NULL, $cycles = 0)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Just copy the entire function to the new file and comment out the two returns described above.

Answer (score 1):

you can define validation rule like this

you can set with a condition

```
if($this->input->post('first_field_name')){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('2ndfield','Field Name','required|callback_myfunction');
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Actually i already find that this is a bug. It picks only one callback if there is no "required" option defined in a rules. Unfortunately, i can't use your approach since i have all rules defined in one file so it's not very handy to do it that way. In form_validation there is no initialized input library so i would have to use $_POST[...] and i don't prefer that much hacking.